# Using Ansible,Jenkins and docker to build fast test environments

Tags: jenkins, docker, ansible

I am planning to build test environment  using ansible, jenkins and docker together.The plan is like this.

Create ansible playbooks for every tool that you are using in your environment and store them on git.
Using jenkins create job to  create docker containers on dev server and use ansible playbooks for provisioning the docker containers.
Jenkins jobs will be created  so that user will have  option to select playbooks that they want to use with docker containers and containers will be built accordingly.

whole concept can be summarized as shown is below image.

[image: Devops]

The benefits i see are

Automatic replication of exact production environments.
Scale your test environment as per requirement.
Provide different platforms for application  testing on a single server.
Faster integration testing.
Promote agile methodology.
Freedom to develop and customize the test environment.
Developers and testers can create  environments on their own even if they don't know anything regarding OS,configuration.
Test the deployment of the app in a clean environment, a fresh build.

Has any one implemented such type of environment architecture,i would like to discuss the feasibility actual benefits of the same.

Comment: how did it go? were you successful? Please share your experience.

Answer (score 4):

I am using a similar but different approach:

- Define Dockerfiles or chef/puppet/ansible/salt provisioning. As in your approach.
- Putting those descriptions under version control. As in your approach.
- Using Jenkins A to CI- and Nightly Building Images and Uploading them into a registry. In order to manage different versions and keeping old images. This introduces a image registry in your diagram.
- Extending those images with Jenkins-Swarm slaves. This enables ad-hoc deployment in your Jenkins environment.

Here I separate between building of the software and the building of the build slaves themselves.

- I deploy a Jenkins B in order to build the software on environments.
- Now I choose between container that I want to deploy permanently and build containers I want to deploy on demand.

  - Permanent containers, which are heavily used by build jobs, are started as swarm slaves and exchanged daily by nightly builds.
  - Ad-hoc containers are managed by the Jenkins-Docker-Plugin.
  - For more complex environment configurations I use docker-compose to manage ad-hoc availability.
  - For ad-hoc environments, namely VMs for running those configurations, I use docker-swarm.

Diagram:
[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing your user case It seems to be nice and i will also check the same.

Comment: Could you please put a diagram like @thinkmonster :) ?

Comment: Thank you @maybeg,it also makes things more clearer to me.

Comment: @maybeg btw  why do you have two jenkins at place i mean you can also configure different jobs and can manage all using single jenkins.I may have not understood but will please let us know if there is any special significance for using two jenkins.

Comment: I maintain a Jenkins Docker Container at Github: blacklabelops/jenkins. Therefore I tend to deploy more instances because its easier for me. I can separate instances regarding their task and remain flexible in rearranging my infrastructure, e.g. Moving from cloud to cloud. Of course it does no big difference to Jenkins if you put all Jobs inside one instance!

Comment: @maybeg I really like your approach. For an open source software project I setup nightly docker builds of GCC trunk (because the project is the official implementation of Coarray Fortran adopted by GCC) on hub.docker.com using https://github.com/zbeekman/nightly-docker-rebuild

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test with a docker image that has the latest available version of a given package on a given OS, then you need to setup nightly docker image rebuilds. I have a very small, simple project that can get you up and running with nightly docker image rebuilds at https://github.com/zbeekman/nightly-docker-rebuild. I use this to rebuild GCC trunk from source, but you could just as easily use it to install/upgrade packages from a package manager, or deal with any other build/runtime dependency that might be updated upstream and have a potential impact on your project. This way you can catch the issues early, before clients/users encounter them.